# How to upload Xcode project built in beta version?

Tags: app-store, xcode9

I built project in Xcode 9 beta version. I want to upload to Appstore but projects built in beta version are not allowed in app store. What could be the possible solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options.

1. Build your project in Xcode 8.3.
2. Wait for Apple to allow developers to submit projects built with Xcode 9 to the App Store. This option should be available soon because Apple usually releases new iOS versions in mid-September.